# Spring MVC. Form, select - как реализовать выбор Null?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Spring MVC приложение.
Две сущности, связанные Один-ко-многим.
В форме создания первой сущности текстовое поле и select для выбора связанной сущности.

*Как реализовать возможность **не выбирать** связанную сущность?!*

**formFilial.jsp:**

```
[cut]    
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="filial" action="${addingFilial}">
  <label>Имя филиала</label>
  <form:input path="name" type="text" id="name" />

  <label>Руководитель</label>
  <form:select path="employeeByChif.id">                
    <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
      <option value="${employee.id}">${employee.Name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </form:select>

  <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form:form>
[cut]
```

**Filial.java**

```
@Entity
public class Filial implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6449188908114303105L;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Employee employeeByChif;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chif", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Employee getEmployeeByChif() {
        return employeeByChif;
    }

    public void setEmployeeByChif(Employee employeeByChif) {
        this.employeeByChif = employeeByChif;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понадобится немного поднастроить Spring для решения этой проблемы. Во-первых, изменим форму так, чтобы она работала непосредственно со свойством модели

**formFilial.jsp**

```
...
<form:select path="employeeByChif">
     <form:option value="">Нет руководителя</form:option>
     <form:options items="${employees}" itemLabel="Name" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
...
```

Во-вторых, потребуется конвертер, который умеет преобразовывать строки в экземпляры сущности `Employee` и обрабатывать пустые значения

**EmployeeConverter.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

@Component
public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter<String, Employee> {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Override
    public Employee convert(String id) {
        if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return employeeService.get(Long.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

И наконец, конвертер надо зарегистрировать в контексте

**servlet-context.xml**

```
...
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="employeeConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
...
```

Comment: Не работает, т.к. select выбирает int (employeeByChif.id).

Comment: Покажите класс объекта `filial`.

Comment: До конверторов я еще не дошёл... :-)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Filial implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6449188908114303105L;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Employee employeeByChif;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chif", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Employee getEmployeeByChif() { return employeeByChif; }

    public void setEmployeeByChif(Employee employeeByChif) { this.employeeByChif = employeeByChif; }

}
```